# ERROR: (models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the nonexistent field, related field, or lookup 'name'

Tags: django-models

I simply can't understand why I get this error:

(models.E015) 'ordering' refers to the nonexistent field, related field, or lookup 'name'

```
from django.db import models

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    slug = models.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f'/{self.slug}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I guess it is the comma at the end of the name field declaration...

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comma and have it this way:

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('name')
```

Then run the makemigrations && migrate commands.

Answer (score 0):

add '-' ini ordering

```
ordering = ('-name',)
```